# What database privileges does a Wordpress Blog really need?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, privileges

I am setting up a few Wordpress blog sites. I have created a user in mysql that wordpress will use to access its database. The docs say to give this user all privileges on the database.

Does it really need full privileges? I expect not, so does anyone know the min set of privileges that it really needs?

Comment: See also: [MySQL Database User: Which Privileges are needed?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/6424/178)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I grant:

- ALTER
- CREATE
- CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES
- DELETE
- DROP
- INDEX
- INSERT
- LOCK TABLES
- SELECT
- UPDATE

Hope that helps anyone else that looks into this.

Answer (score 6):

I'm no Wordpress expert, but I would recommend it does actually have all privileges apart from GRANT. It will need to be able to create tables and insert/update etc. Several plugins use their own tables, which they create on the fly if they do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

grant select, insert, delete, update, create, drop, alter on myblog